# Convert MTB tire to thin tire

Tags: frames

I have a Mongoose MTB and I'm trying to convert my tires from MTB tires to road tires/thin tires. The frame on my bike is 6061 Aluminum Ledge 2.1 so if anyone knows what kind of tires to switch to please help me out. All help is appreciated! Because I don't know what kind of road tires will fit. And could you recommend cheap tires and dropbars that would be helpful.

Updates: My tire is 53-559 and is 26x1.95

Comment: There are a ton of answers here on why you probably don't actually want to put drop bars on without really thinking about it (especially for a BSO like this). It looks like this bike comes in a 26", 27.5" size so that would determine your tire size. Look at the numbers on the side of the tire to determine whats on there.

Comment: Suggest you have a read the many questions on tire sizes Every size is a compromise, and many people make presumptions that are not always true (such as narrower tires are faster)

Comment: So long as you don't have a 26-inch bike with fractional-width (vs decimal-width) tires you can fairly easily substitute narrower tires.  At some point the tires will be too narrow for the rims, but most rims will handle a tire about 30% narrower than "normal" with no difficulty.  On the side of your current tires is a number such as "57-559".  Make sure the second number (the rim diameter) is the same with any new tires you buy.  The first number is tire width and can be narrower, within reason.

Comment: Scrap the drop bars plan - its not financially feasible, because you're up for replacement brakes/shifters.

Comment: You can probably go down to about a 1.25" width.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @vnoobbikerider. We recommend that all new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking a question [ask] will help too.